# Docker file throwing error when i try to run it "AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I am trying my hands with Docker.

I am trying to install apche2 into ubuntu images.

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN echo "welcome to yellow pages"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y tzdata
RUN apt-get install -y apache2

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

RUN echo 'Hello, docker' > /var/www/index.html

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2"]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

I found a reference online [reference](https://gist.github.com/tcnksm/4381bbe7e8258c1f9e8d)

I have added this line "RUN apt-get install -y tzdata" because it was asking for an option of tzdata and stopping image creation.

Now when I run my image I am getting the below error

```
[Thu Jan 07 09:43:57.213998 2021] [core:warn] [pid 1] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot
```

I am new to docker and it's a bit of a task for me to understand it.

Could anyone help me out of this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be Apache issue, not docker issue. Your conf seems to have errors. You have a parameter there called DefaultRuntimeDir which is pointing ad directory which does not exist in docker. Review your config file and ensure directories you specified in there exist in docker.

You can play within docker by simply:

```sh
docker build -t my_image_name .
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash my_image_name
# now you are in your docker container, you can check if your directories exist
```

Without knowing your config I would simply add one more RUN (I made this path up, you can change it to whatever you like)

```
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/lib/apache/runtime
RUN mkdir -p ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
```

As a side note I would also combine all RUN into single like this:

```
RUN echo "welcome to yellow pages" \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y tzdata apache2 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && mkdir -p /var/www \
    && echo 'Hello, docker' > /var/www/index.html
```

Comment: To check i am not able to run the image. Every time I try an run the image I get this error

Comment: Are you trying to run it locally or in AWS? You can copy your Dockerfile to some temporary folder in your computer (i.e. /tmp) and then run commands above to build and run to troubleshoot locally :)

Comment: Try to add the `ENV` and `RUN` I have posted in last edit, it >>should<< help.

Comment: thank you for the comment and edit to the answer. 
I did try it, now I am getting a new error. ------ >  "
 AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined". 
Is there any docke file somewhere that has apache configured? or should I try all the permutations and combinations?

Comment: I don't know your specific docker file (and also I was not using Apache with AWS), the error you are getting is Apache error - you can simply do the same thing as with APACHE_RUN_DIR. You are running stock apache config so you probably want to craft your own with all of the options which will match your needs. I would simply create Dockerfile locally and play with it, it's much faster than to do it through AWS tools.

Comment: All I am trying to achieve here is: to have a docker file with an ubuntu image with apache2. 
My docker file is in my question that's the whole file.  I am only storing that in AWS ECR.

Comment: I meant - I don't know your specific use case, and since I was thinking about your Dockerfile I got the wrong sentence, sorry :) In short - create this Dockerfile locally, play with it until it works and then use it in AWS. Also you are using stock Apache config (the one shipped with ubuntu apache package) so you probably want to craft your own Apache config.

Comment: oh okay got it will play around a bit. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I took another way to achieve this. 
Build a container on ubuntu and ran it interactively installed apache2 and commented that container to the image

Comment: Sounds like path that worked for you, well done :)